# Unable to execute "testphp" from localhost

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, localhost, lamp

I installed LAMP from unixmen.com, but I am not able to run the php script using localhost. It says:

> Not Found  The requested URL /html/testphp.php was not found on this server.  Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Note! My apache server works fine.

Comment: Will it run a file if it has a `.html` extension from the same directory

Comment: What happens if you try just ::  http://localhost ?

Comment: Or will it run that file if you use `localhost/testphp.php`

Comment: did u start APACHE??

Answer (score 0):

Have you started your lampp server? 
terminal command is

```
sudo/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

provided that is where lampp is installed.

Also the url should be http://localhost/name_of_your_project/testphp.php

Answer (score 0):

first question: this file is first .php what executed in new serve?

case yes: make sure your server is started:

```
sudo/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

verify permission in your file.
or

try access using IP 127.0.0.1

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

your directory html are sub `\var\www\html` ?

try move to one level up

Regards